# Object does not show in render port

Tags: rendering, objects

In my animation, one object simply wont render. I looked at a lot of answers about this issue, but it wont solve my problem.

I'm on Blender 2.78. I've tried to open it in Blender 2.79 but the same thing happens there.

[image]

Comment: Everything's showing up in 2.82.7 You don't have any lighting in the scene except the grey environment...maybe adding additional lights could help.

Comment: No. I don't want light and shadow. Besides, all objects show except one. So there has to be another solution. But thanks anyway